# Display dropdown Choice field in Django admin

Tags: django, django-models, choicefield

I am begin to Django and I start create a simple personal blog. I want to create model Category that related to parrent Category. I have read about [display Foreign Key's choices in django-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348521/how-to-display-foreign-keys-choices-in-django-admin). It only work with some static choices. But I cannot query data from database for choices. This is how I am trying to do:

```html
class Category (models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.CharField(unique=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
    parent_category = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, choice = CATEGORIES_CHOICE)
```

I want `CATEGORIES_CHOICE = Category.object.all()`. Any one have an idea to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a django self-referential foreign key !

```
parent_category = models.ForeignKey("self",blank=True, null=True)
```

or

```
parent_category = models.ForeignKey("Category",blank=True, null=True)
```

it's exactly the same

Comment: It worked but when the first time I create a category. The field parent_category cannot null. So I cannot save it.

Comment: Use `blank=True, null=True` if you want the foreign key to be optional.